# VBA convert week and day to date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with week number and day of week.

Example:
J2 = 18
G2 = Monday

How can I convert this to 2018-04-30?

I can find lots of threads for converting the other way around, meaning date to week. But I can't find anything on week + weekday to date.
Anyone know of a method?

Comment: Main problem is finding your first day of first week. For such you must define your week numbering: Jan 1st/first full week in year beginning at Monday/sunday... After that, any date will be plain `W1D1+(Week-1)*7+Day`

Comment: You have to be aware that there are different definitions for "week number". See for example http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WeekNumbers.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (optional) second argument of the [`WEEKDAY`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) function determines what the first day of the week is.  The two most common choices are:

> `1`: Sunday (`1`) to Saturday (`7`)
>   or
>   `2`: Monday (`1`) to Sunday (`7`)

But, you can start on Wednesday, Friday, etc if you want.  Pick an option now.

So, start with 1<sup>st</sup> January (of whichever unspecified year you're working with), and subtract the weekday of 1<sup>st</sup> January, according to whichever start-day you picked.  This gives you a baseline for **Week 1**.  To get to the start of **Week *n***, you just need to add `7*(n-1)` days.

Finally, you need to add the weekday back on.  I'm going to recommend using `MATCH` on an array.  Your array will be your weekdays, in order, surrounded by curly brackets.  So, for Sunday-to-Saturday, you would use

```
MATCH(G2,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)
```

to get a number from `1` ("Sunday") to `7` ("Saturday"), or `#NA` if cell `G2` does not contain a day-name.

Stick it all together, and you get something like this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),1,1) - WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),1,1),1) + 7*(J2-1) + MATCH(G2,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, necessary comments in code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetDate()
    Dim year As Date, day As Long
    'convert day in G2 to integer
    Select Case Range("G2").Value
        Case "Monday"
            day = 1
        Case "Tuesday"
            day = 2
        'rest of cases
    End Select

    'declare what year you want
    year = "01-01-2018"
    'move from first week to the week specified in J2
    year = DateAdd("d", (Range("J2").Value - 1) * 7, year)
    'move back to first day of the week
    Do While DatePart("w", year, vbMonday) <> 1
        year = DateAdd("w", -1, year)
    Loop
    'find date of particular day
    Do While DatePart("w", year, vbMonday) <> day
        year = DateAdd("w", 1, year)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess your `year` inside the loops should be `day`?

Comment: @Andreas No, my bad, I chose poor name, it should be called `dateToReturn`. And it should be initialized with first of January of the year, which you have to choose. But the code works perfectly as it is (answer to your question is no).

Answer (score 1):

The determination depends critically on your definition of "week number".

If you are using the ISO-8601 definition, where a Week starts on Monday and week 1 contains the first Thursday of the year, you can use this worksheet formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,7),14)+$J$2*7+MATCH($G$2&"*",{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"},0)-1
```

*you may need to change the commas to semicolons depending on your regional settings*

---

To explain:

First, find the last Monday of the previous year:

```
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,7),14)
```

Then add seven(7) times the number of desired weeks:

```
+$J$2*7
```

Then add the number of days from Monday to the desired day for that week:

```
+MATCH($G$2&"*",{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"},0)-1
```